# Find records whose attributes after some change is equal to something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, slug

I would, in MySQL, do something like:

`SELECT * FROM table t WHERE REPLACE(t.field,"find_this","replace_with_this") = 'Something'`

Do you know how can I get something like this in Rails?

For example, this wouldn't work:

`Site.where('name = ?',slugify(something))`

Because I'm comparing the name as it is saved in the database with the slugified form of the variable something.

I want to slugify the attribute 'name' of Site and then compare with something.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
slugified_names = Site.where(field: 'find_this').map(&:slugify)
Site.where(field: slugified_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw SQL in your where clause:

```
Site.where("REPLACE(t.field,'find_this','replace_with_this') = ?", value_to_find)
```